# Changing a Google Map using multiple clicks with jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a Google map within a div set for the coordinates of Troy, Michigan.  I want users to be able to click on links for Miami or South Haven, MI, and then back to Troy again.

The map for Troy loads as expected and I can click on the link for Miami and the maps changes.  But if I uncomment out the function for the South Haven links, like it is now, then all the links go to South Haven.

The map is here: http://www.autoalliancemedia.com/BlancoPC%20Map.html#

I can place the code here or you can view it on the page itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to many syntax errors. Check your console.log messages.

Comment: Please include at least the relevant code in your question, not just a link to your map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zP746/)

```
function map1()
{
var mapTroy = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(42.5803,-83.1431),
  zoom:10,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapTroy);
}

function map2() 
{
  var mapMiami = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(25.7877,-80.2241),
  zoom:10,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapMiami);
}


function map3() 
{
  var mapSouthHaven = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(42.4031,-86.2736),
  zoom:10,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapSouthHaven);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map2);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#miami').click(function() {         
      map2();
    }); 

    $('#shaven').click(function() {
     map3();
    });

    $('#troy').click(function() {
     map1();
    });
});
```

Comment: Dave: Many, many thanks.  Have been away for a bit, and was pleasantly surprised to find your answer on my return. Works like a charm. Gary

Comment: This is the answer.  Question is now closed.

Comment: To mark it as answer, you have to click on right tick mark (left side) near answer.. Thanks